# Custom input element with Ant Design Autocomplete?

Tags: css, reactjs, antd

I want to use Ant design's autocomplete functionality, however I dont want to be limited to their input field look. So I want to style it however I want. Can i do that?

My custom input field

```
const FormInput = styled.input`
    background-color: ${(props) =>
        props.top ? "rgba(122,161,240, 0.3)" : "#EDEDED"};
    font-size: 14pt;
    font-family: var(--san-serif-2);
    font-weight: 300;
    padding: ${(props) =>
        props.percent ? "10px 10px 10px 50px" : "10px 20px 10px 40px"};
    border-radius: 10px;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
    width: 100%;

    &:hover {
        background-color: ${(props) =>
            props.top ? "rgba(122,161,240, 0.4)" : "#E4E4E4"};
    }

    &::placeholder {
        color: rgba(122, 161, 240, 1);
    }
`;
```

The Autocomplete i want to style

```
<AutoComplete
     allowClear
     value={symbol}
     options={options}
     style={{
     width: 200,
     }}
     onSelect={onSelect)
     onSearch={onSearch}
     onChange={onChange}
     placeholder="control mode"
     />
```

It seems like the actual input field is surrounded by a div and thats why stuff like `width` works. However when i do padding and other stuff, the div is the one affected and not the input field inside it.

Comment: Fork your code from one of these: https://ant.design/components/auto-complete/ so that others can debug.

Comment: @m4n0 what? What do you mean? I already copied that autocomplete component right from that link you gave me. Expand the code for the basic usage one and youll find that component. Wdym by fork my code from one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by adding your styled input as a child of `AutoComplete` :

```
<AutoComplete
 allowClear
 value={symbol}
 options={options}
 onSelect={onSelect)
 onSearch={onSearch}
 onChange={onChange}
 placeholder="control mode">
   <FormInput />
 </AutoComplete>
```

Comment: Would just add if anyone ever sees this lmao, youll find that you need to remove the place holder in the autocomplete and instead add it to the custom input. Pretty straight forward tho